# How to set the name of nodes by vue-slider-component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I got an issue of vue-slider-component

following Page is my current test module
https://nightcatsama.github.io/vue-slider-component/#/advanced/order

```
    template:`
    <div>
    <vue-slider
      v-model="value"
      :order="false"
      :tooltip="'always'"
      :process="false"
      :marks="marks"
      :width="600"
      ref="nodevalue">
      <template #tooltip="{ index }">            
        <div v-if="index === 1"></div>
        <div v-else></div>
      </template>
    </vue-slider>
    <get-node-index>
    </get-node-index>                                
  </div>
    `,
    data: function () {
        return {
            columnvalue: [
                {text: 'cow', index: 0},
                {text: 'dog', index: 50},
                {text: 'cat', index: 80}
            ],
            value: [0, 50, 80],
            marks: {
              '100': {
                label: '',
                labelStyle: {
                  left: '100%',
                  margin: '0 0 0 10px',
                  top: '50%',
                  transform: 'translateY(-50%)'
                }
              }
            }
          }
    }
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    VueSlider: window['vue-slider-component']
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      columnvalue: [{
          text: 'cow',
          index: 0
        },
        {
          text: 'dog',
          index: 50
        },
        {
          text: 'cat',
          index: 80
        }
      ],
      value: [0, 50, 80],
      marks: {
        '100': {
          label: '',
          labelStyle: {
            left: '100%',
            margin: '0 0 0 10px',
            top: '50%',
            transform: 'translateY(-50%)'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-slider-component@latest/theme/default.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-slider-component@3.0.43/dist/vue-slider-component.umd.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <vue-slider v-model="value" :order="false" :tooltip="'always'" :process="false" :marks="marks" :width="600" ref="nodevalue">
    <template #tooltip="{ index }">            
        <div v-if="index === 1"></div>
        <div v-else></div>
      </template>
  </vue-slider>
</div>
```

how to set the nodes on slider by my columnvalue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The index value isn't the value of the slider, it's just the index of slider, so you'll need to change your data to reflect that.

I don't know what version of vue your are using, but if youre below 2.6 you'll have to use `slot` and `slot-scope`, either way the main parts are these.

Changing your data to be correct

```
columnvalue: [{
      text: 'cow',
      index: 0
    },
    {
      text: 'dog',
      index: 1
    },
    {
      text: 'cat',
      index: 2
    }
  ]
```

Changing the html to call a `function`

```
<div>{{getText(index)}}</div>
```

And the actual function it's self

```
getText(index) {
    return this.columnvalue.find((v) => v.index == index).text
}
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    VueSlider: window['vue-slider-component']
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      columnvalue: [{
          text: 'cow',
          index: 0
        },
        {
          text: 'dog',
          index: 1
        },
        {
          text: 'cat',
          index: 2
        }
      ],
      value: [0, 50, 80],
      marks: {
        '100': {
          label: '',
          labelStyle: {
            left: '100%',
            margin: '0 0 0 10px',
            top: '50%',
            transform: 'translateY(-50%)'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getText(index) {
      return this.columnvalue.find((v) => v.index == index).text
    }
  }
})
```

```css
#app {
  margin: 80px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.10/vue.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-slider-component@latest/theme/default.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue-slider-component@3.0.43/dist/vue-slider-component.umd.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <vue-slider v-model="value" :order="false" :tooltip="'always'" :process="false" :marks="marks" :width="600" ref="nodevalue">
    <template slot="tooltip" slot-scope="{index}">
      <div>{{getText(index)}}</div>
    </template>
  </vue-slider>
</div>
```